# Choosing the right transformer to replace batteries?

Tags: led, batteries, transformer, lighting

I have an idea for a hack I'd like to build, but I need some help figuring out the right transformer. Let me know if there's a better place to post this sort of request.

I have some exterior LED path lights that work on 4 C-Cell batteries each.  There are 6 of them, so having to replace the batteries is relatively expensive and a bit of a pain. Looking at the lights, I see that I could easily solder wires to the battery contacts and replace the batteries with a transformer.  I could run a low voltage wire indoors to a transformer and never have to worry about batteries again.  My problem is that I'm not sure what transformer to get.

I did some simple math but I have no electronics background, so I would appreciate getting guidance from folks that have more knowledge about this stuff.

Here's what I know:

Each light takes 4 C-cell batteries in line. That is they are stacked one on top of the other with positive terminal touching negative.  I think that means I'd need to add the voltages together meaning 4 x 1.5V = 6V required.

I have no idea how much power each light draws (specs don't say anywhere) and the math I did doesn't seem to make sense. I know that alkaline batteries are normally rated for about 8000 mAh.  The manufacturer of the light claims that the lights last about 50 hours before needing the batteries replaced.  8000 / 50 = 160 mAh draw.  That seems really low to me.  Is 160 mAh a reasonable amount for an LED light (supposedly 80 lumens output if that helps)?

So if I multiply that out 6 * 160 = 960 mAh required.  I want to be able to add a few lights so let's double that (so just under 2A).

Does that mean I need a 6V transformer that can do 2 amps?  That seems really low to me, so I'm hoping someone with electronics knowledge can provide some help figuring out what I really need.

Any guidance or nudges in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: mAh is a measure of charge. mA is a measure of current.

Comment: And it's not low, in fact! LEDs are remarkably efficient, especially if what you're used to is incandescent lights, aka bright heaters.

Comment: @felthry Thanks. So I'm going in the wrong direction then? how would I figure this out?

Comment: You're not going in the wrong direction. 8000mAh/50h = 160mA. You just forgot that you're dividing by hours. Though you might have some difficulty using a transformer--these lights want DC, and transformers only work with AC!

Comment: @Felthry hmm. I was able to find something like that on amazon for pretty cheap.  Wouldn't something like this work: 
https://www.amazon.com/inShareplus-Mounted-100-240V-Transformer-Connector/dp/B01GCI99OG/

Comment: Yes, that would work, but it's not a transformer. Even though it claims to be. It's an AC/DC converter, almost certainly some sort of switching type. If it _did_ involve a mains-frequency transformer it'd be a hell of a lot bigger than that, not to mention heavier.

Comment: @Felthry Fantastic. Thanks. Does the rated amps matter? Should I get the 3A version JIC? or the 5A?  Or is that just a waste since it doesn't seem like I'll need even 2A?

Comment: @BenRiga A higher-rated power supply will probably last longer and provide more reliable service. Get the higher rated supply that you can afford. Keep in mind that long runs of copper wire will drop voltage. Use the heaviest gauge wire you can afford to apply or else take a look at the resistance per foot for whatever wire gauge you are considering and use Ohm's law to work out the voltage drop given, say, \$1.5\:\text{A}\$ as the current. Don't forget that this is wire going out, plus wire coming back, so twice the distance to the furthest light.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

160mA at 6V is about 1W that would be easily suffucuent for a fairly bright LED path light.

If you're not equipped to measure the current consumption of the lights 
maybe go for a 2A 6V supply that should be plenty if you estimate is in the right ballpark.

You could probably even use a 5V 2A "phone charger" as battery powered devices are usually designed to operate from as low as 1.1V per cell so 5V should be plenty.